# Xamarin CarouselPage doesn't work in Window Phone 8.1?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to make CarouselPage in my Xamarin Project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ABP.Views.ProcessSurveysPage">
  <ContentPage>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Red" />
      <BoxView Color="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
  <ContentPage>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Green" />
      <BoxView Color="Green" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
  <ContentPage>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Blue" />
      <BoxView Color="Blue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
</CarouselPage>
```

Here is xaml.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ABP.Views
{
    public partial class ProcessSurveysPage : CarouselPage
    {
        public ProcessSurveysPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = "Current Bookings";
        }
    }
}
```

This is caller.

```
private void GotoProcessSurveysPage(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Navigation.PushAsync(new ProcessSurveysPage()));
    //await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new DateSearchFilterView());
}
```

I tested on Android, Window 8.

But while I deployed it on my window phone 8.1 and swiped on pages but any action has not happened.

How can I fix this?

What's my wrong?

Comment: Try to use CarouselView

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/